# Returning two Json or save it

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have a site developed in codeigniter and I have a model where I have to create two Json but I don't know if is better to save it into my server or pass it itno the controller and after in the view but how?

This is my model simplify:

```
public function calledFromController(){
   //code...
   $this->makeRequest();
}

public function makeRequest(){
  //code...
  foreach ($foo as $foo2){
     $values[] = $foo2->value;
  }

  foreach ($hello as $hello2){
     $values_hello[] = $hello2->value;
  }

  //save it into my server
  $file = fopen('foo.json','w+');
  fwrite($file, $foo);
  fclose($file);

  $file2 = fopen('hello.json','w+');
  fwrite($file2, $file2);
  fclose($file2);
}
```

Now I save it, but can be a very lot of data and after I have to open each json and parse it into javascript (backbone).
Is better this mode or return this two json (I have to mantain separate Json)?
Is I have to return this two Json how Can I do?
From my controller I call the function calledFromController in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by creating an array and returning the array if you want to return both the json:

```
$data          = array();
$data['foo']   = $foo;
$data['hello'] = $hello;
return $data;
```

In the controller:

```
$return = $this->model->function();
$foo    = $return['foo'];
$hello  = $return['hello'];
```

Comment: Can you please develop your answer in how can I retrieve this data into controller or view if I return $data from my model?

Comment: Is it what you wanted? Or do you need anything else? @AlessandroMinoccheri

Comment: Yes what I wanted. Thanks! Accepted and +1